# Добавить в preg_match ещё один вариант срабатывания

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.

Есть такая строчка:

```
if preg_match("/href=/", $commentdata['comment_content']) {
```

Срабатывание происходит по наличию в тексте *href=*
Как сюда добавить, чтобы срабатывало ещё и по другому значению, к примеру, *src=*

Comment: `'~(?:href|src)=~'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if preg_match("/href=|src=/", $commentdata['comment_content']) {